# Is it bad practice to change the "From" name when sending emails?

Tags: email, security, smtp

I have an email module that lets users send an email to their city councillor. As of now, the From address of every email sent is `My Cool Website <info@mycoolwebsite.ca>`.

Is it considered email spoofing or bad practice for me to set the From address as `Julie Ali <info@mycoolwebsite.ca>`, with Julie Ali being the name of the user sending the email (which is pulled from the "Email your city councillor" form they fill out). Will this negatively affect my domain's reputation, or is this standard practice?

Comment: I would not recommend it. Why take a chance?

Comment: If the recipient replies to the email, does it get back to "Julie Ali"? If not then that's confusing/frustrating for the user.

Comment: When the recipient replies, it goes to `Julie Ali <juliesOwnEmail@email.com>`

Answer (score 1):

As long as the email address has valid SPF and DKIM settings, it won't be a problem.  In an organisation many people may send from one address.

Comment: I think some e-mail filters compare names if more than one e-mail is received. It has been a long time since I was involved in e-mail filters. Who knows these days? Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc haven't heard of that.  Of course nothing can stop the recipient deciding that all these emails are a nuisance and either filter them to /dev/null or have them blacklisted somewhere.